# SSMS ALTER VIEW query repeatedly gets me "Invalid column name" when that is not the case

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Intellisense refresh is not working and there are no other views with the same name under different schemas to confuse the query.  The original table does have all columns stated as invalid in the error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 6, Procedure TableauSales, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'PurchaseDate'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 6, Procedure TableauSales, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'UnitsSold'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 6, Procedure TableauSales, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name 'GrossRevenue'.

Query:

```
ALTER VIEW [MemberGrowth].[TableauSales] AS
SELECT PurchDate,
PlatformDetail,
LicenseType,
DistributionMethod,
Product,
SUM(cur_GrossRevenue) as cur_GrossRevenue,
SUM(cur_UnitsSold) as cur_UnitsSold,
SUM(pre_GrossRevenue) as pre_GrossRevenue,
SUM(pre_UnitsSold) as pre_UnitsSold


FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(
(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate,
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,

 /*Add any segmentation you want above */

cast(PurchaseDate As Date) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -7, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)

UNION ALL

(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate, 
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,

/*Add any segmentation you want above */

DATEADD(DAY, -6, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -8, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)

UNION ALL
(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate,
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,
 /*Add any segmentation you want above */
DATEADD(DAY, -5, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -9, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)
UNION ALL

(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate,
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,
 /*Add any segmentation you want above */

DATEADD(DAY, -4, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -10, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)
UNION ALL

(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate, 
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,
/*Add any segmentation you want above */

DATEADD(DAY, -3, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -11, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)

UNION ALL

(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate,
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,
 /*Add any segmentation you want above */

DATEADD(DAY, -2, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -12, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
DISTINCT cast(PurchaseDate As Date) AS PurchDate,
PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod,
Product,
/*Add any segmentation you want above */


DATEADD(DAY, -1, PurchaseDate) as pre_week,
DATEADD(DAY, -13, PurchaseDate) as week_before
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales)
  ) a

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT PurchaseDate as cur_week,
 PlatformDetail as cur_PlatformDetail, 
 /*Add any segmentation you want above */

 GrossRevenue as cur_GrossRevenue,
 UnitsSold as cur_UnitsSold

 FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales) b
ON a.pre_week = b.cur_week AND
 /*Join by any segmentation you are doing below */

 a.PlatformDetail = b.cur_PlatformDetail) c

JOIN

(SELECT PurchaseDate as sec_date,
 PlatformDetail as pre_PlatformDetail,

 /*Add any segmentation you want above */

 GrossRevenue as pre_GrossRevenue,
 UnitsSold as pre_UnitsSold
 FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales) d
ON c.week_before = d.sec_date
/*Join by Any segmentation you are doing below */
AND c.cur_PlatformDetail = d.pre_PlatformDetail

/*groupby by Any segmentation you are doing below */

GROUP BY PurchDate, PlatformDetail, LicenseType, DistributionMethod, Product
```

Comment: The native intellsense is pretty craptastic. You may have to close SSMS entirely when the refresh local cache doesn't work.

Comment: We would need to see the query and know the structure of the tables.  Intellisense not refreshing won't cause the error.  You can force it to refresh with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`, but that won't fix the error.

Comment: Or if there is an actual error that has nothing at all to do with intellisense. Is it just the red squiggly in the editor or an actual exception when you try to execute the alter script?

Comment: The error is with the column name which doesn't exist from a table.

Comment: I have closed out SSMS many times with no remedy.

Comment: If the server gives you an error on executing the `ALTER VIEW` command, the *server is right*, regardless of what SMSS shows or does not show. Keep that in mind as you try to diagnose things -- eliminate the truly impossible, not the merely unlikely.

Comment: I will post the code back in the original explanation.

Comment: Again...is it a red squiggly or an actual exception when running the alter script? If your column is an external one across a linked server the intellisense will never "see" it but your script will execute just fine.

Comment: See the updated question above.

Comment: @DLaviolette Can we see the column structure of the `MemberGrowth.TableauSales` table?

Comment: The server takes forever to run a simple query but here are the column names: SELECT TOP (1000) [CountryCode]
      ,[PurchaseDate]
      ,[Edition]
      ,[DistributionMethod]
      ,[LicenseType]
      ,[Platform]
      ,[PlatformDetail]
      ,[Product]
      ,[ProductCategory]
      ,[ProductSubCategory]
      ,[DataSource]
      ,[UnitsSold]
      ,[GrossRevenue]
  FROM [MemberGrowth].[TableauSales]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue - you are trying to do the following:

```
ALTER VIEW [MemberGrowth].[TableauSales]
```

And the query for the view references the object:

```
FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales
```

Look familiar?

You're trying to alter the view definition by using a query that references the view.

You might want to look at the existing view definition to see the actual underlying table it is referencing.

Comment: Wait, so do I change the ALTER VIEW line or the FROM lines? Let me rephrase, kind of.... If I reference the original table the ALER VIEW will still just alter the view and not the underlying table, correct?

Comment: @DLaviolette I can't really answer that - it depends on if `MemberGrowth.TableauSales` is a `VIEW` or a `TABLE`.  Either way, you'll definitely need to take a closer look at how it's defined currently before making changes.  (Right-click on the object in the object explorer and script to create)

Comment: MemberGrowth.TableauSales is a view created off another view...  By replacing the FROM MemberGrowth.TableauSales with the original view and leaving the ALTER VIEW statement as it should just alter the MemberGrowth.TableauSales view....I think?

Comment: @DLaviolette Yes, that would work.  As long as the query looks correct with the original view in the `FROM`.

Comment: A view can't reference itself....there is something else funky going on here that we are not seeing. Great catch on the SNAFU though!!!

Comment: Yeah, I've got some adjusting of column names to do from the original view.  Thats on me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: It isn't just column names you need to fix here. Once you fix the column names your view will create with a self reference just fine. But you won't be able to select from it. You will get this exception. select * from sys.messages where message_id = 4429